# On plotting the Weibull distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

First: How can I plot the Weibull distribution with parameters `a = 2` and `b = 3.5` on the range of `x = {0, 20}`?

Second: for the following 20 observations, I want a histogram with a plot of the Weibull distribution `a = 2.29` and `b = 2.95` and exponential distribution `a = 1.95`, all in the same plot.

The observation data:

```
{0.4, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7, 0.1, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 
 0.4, 0.7, 0.5, 0.3, 0.9}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Plot[PDF[WeibullDistribution[2, 3.5], x], {x, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

```
data = {0.4, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.7, 
   0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7, 0.1, 
   0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 0.4, 0.7, 0.5, 0.3, 0.9};

Show[
 Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #],
    {x, 0, 1}] & /@
  {WeibullDistribution[2.29, 2.95],
   ExponentialDistribution[1.95]}]
```

[image]

However, your specified distributions are not the best fit to the data. Use `EstimatedDistribution` to get the best fit.

```
wd = EstimatedDistribution[data, WeibullDistribution[a, b]]
```

> WeibullDistribution[2.70657, 0.574639]

```
ed = EstimatedDistribution[data, ExponentialDistribution[a]]
```

> ExponentialDistribution[1.95238]

```
Show[
 Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #], {x, 0, 1}] & /@
  {wd, ed}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Bob..can we use manipulate with the last graph (i mean Histogram + distribution curve + Manipulate] All in one graph, manipulate {a,o,3} ???

Comment: You could put this into a `Manipulate`; however, it would not return any better results than the `EstimatedDistribution`.