# Fitting and plotting Weibull distribution

Tags: plotting, fitting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

1. How can I find the best fitted  2-parameter Weibull's distribution (PDF) to describe my data? How can i plot my data and estimated distribution all in one graph?
2. How can I show/compare results of different methods of finding both weibull's parameters (maximum likelihood, linear regression...)?
3. completely optional; are there other interesting statistical informations concerning my problem that i should ask about here but I didn't due to my lack of experience with data analysis? any recommendations are very welcome and helpfull...

---

```
data = {{18.12, 0.}, {18.36, 0.}, {18.6, 0.00749}, {18.84, 0.00749}, {19.08, 
  0.}, {19.32, 0.00749}, {19.56, 0.03747}, {19.8, 0.02248}, {20.04, 
  0.02248}, {20.28, 0.08243}, {20.52, 0.05246}, {20.76, 
  0.02998}, {21., 0.08993}, {21.24, 0.09742}, {21.48, 
  0.06745}, {21.72, 0.16487}, {21.96, 0.13489}, {22.2, 
  0.27728}, {22.44, 0.13489}, {22.68, 0.16487}, {22.92, 
  0.31475}, {23.16, 0.14988}, {23.4, 0.32224}, {23.64, 
  0.2473}, {23.88, 0.22482}, {24.12, 0.26978}, {24.36, 
  0.20983}, {24.6, 0.23981}, {24.84, 0.14239}, {25.08, 
  0.13489}, {25.32, 0.07494}, {25.56, 0.06745}, {25.8, 
  0.04496}, {26.04, 0.07494}, {26.28, 0.08243}, {26.52, 
  0.02998}, {26.76, 0.02248}, {27., 0.01499}, {27.24, 
  0.02248}, {27.48, 0.02998}, {27.72, 0.02248}, {27.96, 
  0.00749}, {28.2, 0.}, {28.44, 0.}, {28.68, 0.}, {28.92, 
  0.00749}, {29.16, 0.00749}, {29.4, 0.}, {29.64, 0.}, {29.88, 0.}}
```

Comment: Look up `FindDistributionParameters[]`.

Comment: tried that. i get that one or more data points are not in support of weibull distr... :-(

Comment: Related: [63074](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63074/on-plotting-the-weibull-distribution), [61424](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61424/estimating-parameters-of-a-custom-distribution)

Comment: Should've mentioned that to begin with… it didn't work even with a good guess?

Comment: yeah, guess i should, sorry... i'm a newbie when it comes to mathematica... what do you mean by 'good guess'? or could it be sth wrong with my data?

Comment: [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) is a better SE site for your general stats questions.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that you are not fitting raw data to a distribution, you are fitting the emperical PDF of that distribution (probably in terms of values, percentages pairs). That won't work as the functions you are using (I guess `EstimatedDistribution`or `FindDistributionParameters`) expect the raw measurement data, not frequencies.

To deal with your specific data you need either `FindFit` or `NonlinearModelFit` and fit that to the PDF of the Weibull distribution (and I don't think your data is OK for a two-parameter Weibull):

```
f[x_] = 
NonlinearModelFit[
   data, 
   {PDF[WeibullDistribution[α, β, μ], x], α > 0 && β > 0}, 
   {α, β, μ}, x
]["BestFit"];

Show[
 ListPlot[data],
 Plot[f[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a perfect place to use `WeightedData`.

```
dist = EstimatedDistribution[WeightedData @@ Transpose[data], WeibullDistribution[a, b]]

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 30}]]
```

[image]

It is worth noting that observations with zero weights are ignored because they do not contribute to the likelihood.

Comment: @Andy I believe what Karsten means here is that in my FindFit all numbers are treated equally, although there is more data in the higher frequencies. I guess that's true, but I suppose that the difference in modelling assumptions/methods between NonLinearModelFit and EstimatedDistribution plays a role too.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I've unintentionally made things too complicated by trying to point out that the zeros get ignored. I was hoping to not get into any more detail than that :) Removing all reference to `NonlinearModelFit`

Answer (score 4):

As @Sjoerd C. de Vries states: one really wants to use the raw data.  However, your data is binned with (I assume) the bin midpoints along with the associated relative frequency.  And ideally you should account for the binning (although in this case it doesn't make much difference in the estimates and because as stated by others the fit is not hot anyway).  If you had many fewer bins, then you would definitely need to account for the binning to get appropriate estimates.

To get the original integer frequencies divide by the smallest relative frequency - in this case it works because I'm sure you'll verify that the smallest positive frequency is 1 and corresponds to the relative frequency 0.07494.  Further "proof" is that all of the other relative frequencies turn into numbers awfully close to integers.)

Here is the code to obtain the maximum likelihood estimates accounting for the binning of the data:

```
(* Bin mid-point and frequency *)
data = {{18.6, 1}, {18.84, 1}, {19.32, 1}, {19.56, 5}, {19.8, 
    3}, {20.04, 3}, {20.28, 11}, {20.52, 7}, {20.76, 4}, {21, 
    12}, {21.24, 13}, {21.48, 9}, {21.72, 22}, {21.96, 18}, {22.2, 
    37}, {22.44, 18}, {22.68, 22}, {22.92, 42}, {23.16, 20}, {23.4, 
    43}, {23.64, 33}, {23.88, 30}, {24.12, 36}, {24.36, 28}, {24.6, 
    32}, {24.84, 19}, {25.08, 18}, {25.32, 10}, {25.56, 9}, {25.8, 
    6}, {26.04, 10}, {26.28, 11}, {26.52, 4}, {26.76, 3}, {27, 
    2}, {27.24, 3}, {27.48, 4}, {27.72, 3}, {27.96, 1}, {28.92, 
    1}, {29.16, 1}};

(* Width of each bin *)
binWidth = 24/100;

(* Define log likelihood of binned data *)
logLikelihood[k_, lambda_] := Sum[data[[i, 2]] Log[
    Exp[-((data[[i, 1]] - binWidth/2)/lambda)^k] - 
     Exp[-((data[[i, 1]] + binWidth/2)/lambda)^k]],
  {i, Length[data[[All, 1]]]}]

(* Find maximum likelihood estimates *)
sol = FindMaximum[{logLikelihood[k, lambda], 
   k > 0 && lambda > 0}, {{k, 10}, {lambda, 24}}]
```

which results in

```
{-1910., {k -> 14.0869, lambda -> 24.205}}
```

A plot of the fit is given by

```
(* Plot results *)
p1 = Plot[(k/lambda) (x/lambda)^(k - 1) Exp[-(x/lambda)^k] /. 
    sol[[2]], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]] - binWidth, 
    Max[data[[All, 1]]] + binWidth}];
n = Total[data[[All, 2]]];
p2 = ListPlot[
   Table[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]/(n binWidth) }, {i, 
     Length[data[[All, 1]]]}], AxesOrigin -> {18, 0}];
Show[{p2, p1}]
```

[image: Weibull fit]

**ADDITION:**  Estimates of variance and covariance can be obtained also (although good estimates of variance for a poor fit doesn't do one much good):

```
(* First partial derivatives *)
pLogL = D[logLikelihood[k, lambda], {{k, lambda}}];

(* Estimates of variances and the covariance of k and lambda *)
var = -Inverse[D[pLogL, {{k, lambda}}] /. sol[[2]]]
(* {{0.179681, 0.0108254}, {0.0108254, 0.00598091}} *)

(* Check to see that the first partial derivatives are close to zero *)
pLogL /. sol[[2]]
(* {2.13724*10^-7, -9.42956*10^-9} *)
```

Comment: The mean $x$-axis values within each bin do not occur at the mid point of each bin. One should do a survey of fit functions then test them. The problem as stated suggests approximately Poisson type counting data. This is not directly related to maximum likelihood.

Comment: @Carl  We will have to agree to disagree.  Maximum likelihood does not assume that the mean of the raw values occurs at the midpoints of each bin.  Only the regression approach does.  And while the counts might be very well approximated by a Poisson, the counts are not available.  Only the relative frequencies are available (unless the guess made by me to figure out what the counts are is correct).

Comment: The guess you made is likely correct but I am not so sure it matters relatively speaking. That is, $\frac{(a0 x1)^{1/2}}{(a0 x2)^{1/2}}=\frac{x1^{1/2}}{x2^{1/2}}$

Comment: Regarding the midpoint, ML does not assume that. The assumption that is troubling is that bins can be used instead of original values and then perform ML with impunity. I also do not believe without proof that this is a two parameter Weibull, which is the more important question.

Comment: @Carl  It shouldn't be troubling.  All ML assumes is that the form of the likelihood is correct (i.e., that one is sampling from a Weibull in this case) and that a count in the bin is known (as opposed to just knowing the relative frequency).  There is no assumption either assumed or needed that the mean of the raw observations matches even closely to the midpoint of the bin.  That is basic maximum likelihood.

Comment: @Carl Having the count vs the relative frequency does not matter in the realized estimates for maximum likelihood but it does matter strongly in any estimate of precision of those estimates.  If I tossed a coin several times and got an estimate of the probability of heads being 0.5466, wouldn't you want to be able to get an estimate of precision for that result?  You can't do that unless you know how many times I tossed the coin.  "For every estimate there shalt be a proper estimate of precision."

Comment: Precision of the wrong answer is not as useful and having the right answer and not knowing how precise it is. As you can see from the binned data, good precision is not to be had, the model will never be a precise representation, the noise is way too high. It is not that I do not care about precision, I do, but it is not the most important consideration. Consider it this way, worry first about first order validity, and second about second order validity.

Comment: Seems that it doesn't matter which one does, MLE or Poisson Norm regression, as below, and on our talk page, our combined efforts seem to have arrived at the same thing to within tiny differences. Your help has been very much appreciated. +1

Answer (score 2):

Let's first test which distribution is more likely. However, we should treat FindDistribution results with a grain of salt, it may be suggestive, but there are problems with the definition of AIC, which is not industry standard, e.g., see https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2198153 and prior links to it. Worse, this is the wrong routine to use for this data (mismatch), but I'm just mucking with the data to get ideas as to what might be worth testing.

```
FindDistribution[data[[All, 2]], 5, All]
```

[image]
What I did was ignore the binning with the command data[[All, 2]], and doing that doesn't really harm anything other than shift the data by about 23 to the left. This suggests that perhaps a normal distribution may be good enough, and it would take a 3 parameter Weibull distribution to be competitive. Now this may be a three parameter Weibull distribution. In any case, treating it like a normal distribution one can do another thing that seems like heresy:

```
f1 = FindFit[data,c0 PDF[NormalDistribution[mu,sigma], x], {{c0, 1}, {mu, 23}, {sigma, 0.11}}, x]
Show[ListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Thickness[0.018],PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[.3]]], Plot[Evaluate[c0 PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], x] /. f1], {x, 18, 30}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Which shows the data with its fit function. There is likely some skewness, so one could try a three parameter Weibull distribution. Given the magnitude of the $x$-values, without a location parameter, I don't think a two-parameter Weibull would work as well.

**Edit**
Worrying about ML or not ML is not a first consideration. Before that let's further examine which distribution is in play. So how did Sjoerd C. de Vries, in his answer, know to try a three parameter Weibull distribution other by doing something like I did above? Here is another way of showing a three parameter Weibull.

```
fit=NonlinearModelFit[data2,kk PDF[WeibullDistribution[a0,a1,a2],x],{kk,a0,a1,a2},x,WorkingPrecision->30,MaxIterations->1000];
Show[ListPlot[data2],Plot[fit[x],{x,18,30}],Frame->True]
fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

[image]

{kk->0.964661496866093819527120602321,a0->4.72300143536200858818774078537,a1->6.80075698971527535007544086964,a2->17.0803838666758819512633107980}

Further steps are to model the data **as is**, e.g., with a Poisson loss function as it is count data (see JimB's answer) and note that we haven't proven anything here. We still need to test distributions for goodness of fit to gain more insight.

Also note this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104279/42558, which includes

```
(* GerneralizedLinearModelFit - logically the same as maximum
likelihood estimate *)
glm = GeneralizedLinearModelFit[data, xx^2, xx,
ExponentialFamily -> "Poisson", LinearOffsetFunction -> 1,
IncludeConstantBasis -> False, LinkFunction -> "IdentityLink",
WorkingPrecision -> 100];
```

That is, if we have a Poisson process, and model it as such, the claim is that it will not differ from ML. To show this, with work in the chat link https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137349/room-for-jimb-and-carl, the results of modelling are from simulation of a normal distribution with a sample size of 10000 performed 500 times. The synthetic mean "truth" value is 23 and the "true" SD is 3/2. Notice that the 95% tolerance ellipses largely superimpose, and the fits themselves are from fitting of bin width convolution of the normal distribution in both cases, MLE binned fitting, and regression binned fitting. To claim that regression is somehow inferior in quality to MLE, we would need to be careful as to which context we are speaking of, and in this case, there doesn't seem to be much of a difference for binned data.

[image]

To do ML, we can use @JimB's guess as to what the number of realizations are in each bin, duplicate that many samples in each bin at the bin location, and just use FindDistributionParameters, which is an ML procedure:

```
data3 = Rationalize[{{18.6, 1}, {18.84, 1}, {19.32, 1}, {19.56, 
5}, {19.8, 3}, {20.04, 3}, {20.28, 11}, {20.52, 7}, {20.76, 
4}, {21, 12}, {21.24, 13}, {21.48, 9}, {21.72, 22}, {21.96, 
18}, {22.2, 37}, {22.44, 18}, {22.68, 22}, {22.92, 42}, {23.16, 
20}, {23.4, 43}, {23.64, 33}, {23.88, 30}, {24.12, 36}, {24.36, 
28}, {24.6, 32}, {24.84, 19}, {25.08, 18}, {25.32, 10}, {25.56, 
9}, {25.8, 6}, {26.04, 10}, {26.28, 11}, {26.52, 4}, {26.76, 
3}, {27, 2}, {27.24, 3}, {27.48, 4}, {27.72, 3}, {27.96, 
1}, {28.92, 1}, {29.16, 1}}, 0]; 
datamess = Flatten[Table[data3[[i, 1]], {i, Length[data3]}, {j, 1, data3[[i, 2]]}]];

H1 = FindDistributionParameters[datamess, WeibullDistribution[a0, a1, a2], WorkingPrecision -> 30]
QQ1 = QuantilePlot[datamess, WeibullDistribution[a0, a1, a2] /. H1, PlotLabel -> "3 parm Weibull", ImageSize -> Medium];
H2 = FindDistributionParameters[datamess, WeibullDistribution[a0, a1], WorkingPrecision -> 30]
QQ2 = QuantilePlot[datamess, WeibullDistribution[a0, a1] /. H2, PlotLabel -> "2 parm Weibull", ImageSize -> Medium];
H3 = FindDistributionParameters[datamess, NormalDistribution[a0, a1], WorkingPrecision -> 30]
QQ3 = QuantilePlot[datamess, NormalDistribution[a0, a1] /. H3, PlotLabel -> "Normal", ImageSize -> Medium];
Print[QQ1, QQ2, QQ3]
```

Which gives us
[image]
From the QQ plots, we can see the problem with just duplicating samples, we get a dotted step pattern $...\cdots$. Despite this, it is quite clear that the Normal distribution (see left tail) fits slightly better than the 3 parameter Weibull, which in turn fits much better than the 2 parameter Weibull. In doing so, we are not so much concerned with getting an exact answer for each fit, but are answering the question as to which fit equation is appropriate. To see how to get reproducible answers that are largely methods independent, follow the procedure in the chat link. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137349/room-for-jimb-and-carl

Comment: This is not a regression problem and ‘FindFit’ is inappropriate for several reasons.

Comment: @JimB Regression is also not inappropriate for several reasons. For one thing, it is likely MVUE given equidistant $x$-axis data as contrasted to a random variate. That is, there is no $x$-axis random variate, only $y$-axis variability such that least squares in $y$ is not inappropriate. I would like to see why you think this inappropriate, for example, MLR would assume random variate structure of the $x$-axis data, which information was destroyed by binning. So, please explain your reasoning, and if you wish we can continue this elsewhere.

Comment: Let me count the ways:  (1) the sample size is (almost certainly) 556 (the total frequency count) and not the number of bins (50), (2) The regression you use assumes a constant variance which is certainly not true (relative frequencies close to 0.5 have higher variance although somewhat reduced by having more observations), (3) Because of (1) and (2) the estimates of precision will not be appropriate – although `FindFit` doesn’t produce any estimates of precision which is another reason for not using `FindFit`.  I'm sure I can find more reasons.

Comment: However, I will concede that your approach can get one starting values for an appropriate approach such as maximum likelihood or the method of moments.

Comment: I've set up a chat room as you have suggested:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137349/room-for-jimb-and-carl

Comment: One approach to obtain a relative measure of goodness-of-fit is to use AIC (or AICc).  But to use that measure, you'll need to use maximum likelihood.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion.

Comment: @JimB There are lots of measures of goodness-of-fit, and, they all have warts including AIC. No, I don't rely on AIC, I have lots of posts that show why that is. For instance, AIC is only asymptotically valid, and unless you have hundreds of data points, and very few parameters, you may be asking for trouble. More, R$^2$, adjusted R$^2$ BIC and the lot of them break down when the number of parameters approaches the sample size. The best way I have found to compare models is to compare the answers to against general functional models of the same number of parameters.

Comment: I think you're throwing in roadblocks that just are unnecessary for this particular question.  There are only 2 or 3 parameters here.  But because regression seems to be a go-to procedure, the best book/advice out there is https://www.google.com/books/edition/Regression_Modeling_Strategies/94RgCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=inauthor:%22Frank+E.+Harrell+,+Jr.%22&printsec=frontcover and there's a video from the author at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwGyoo-D8iY.

Comment: @JimB Yes, I know you think that. I am worried about misuse of procedure just like you are, it's just that my experiences, and the testing I've done did not lead me to the same place as it did for you. You said you were going to try the Poisson norm, please do. I am willing to investigate your claims to exhaustion, do the same for me please.

Comment: @JimB I acknowledge that what I do is not what many people believe, I do not base my decisions upon belief but am convinced by primary evidence.